# How to validate Facebook user token server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-c#-sdk

I am having problem understanding how to implement a Facebook login workflow for my web app. I am stuck in the validation of the user token server side.

I am using [C# SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk) library. I am trying to validate the user token using the following code:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
    fb.AppId = "0000000000000";
    fb.AppSecret = "000000000000000000000";    

    dynamic result = fb.Get("debug_token", new { input_token = c_accessToken });
```

I get the following error when running the Get command.

```
OAuthException - #100) (#100) You must provide an app access token
or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app
```

I changed the appId and appSecret for privacy reasons, but I double checked them and they are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send App Access Token That is the error you are getting. To get an App access token follow this documentation from facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens

To generate App Access Token you need to make a GET request from your `FacebookClient()` or using `HttpClient()`to this API endpoint.

```
GET /oauth/access_token
?client_id={app-id}
&client_secret={app-secret}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

this the documentation link for 'debug_token' endpoint 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling